# Can't make TP-Link WN8200ND wifi adapter work. No networks displayed

Tags: 18.04, wireless, virtualbox, realtek, tp-link

I'm trying to make the USB WiFi adapter work but I can't.
I followed the steps mentioned in the github 8192eu drivers README and it seems to be installed but when I try to connect it shows me no networks, even if in Windows 10 I see a lot of them.

Sometimes it shows me a network (only one) but after a minute or two it disappears. It looks like the antenna power was very weak.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox.

when I use `lsmod` I can see 8192eu listed, but when I use `sudo lshw -c network` it displays `driver=rtl8192eu`

Is that normal? I mean

8192eu != rtl8192eu

I have edited `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and added the line `backlist rtl8xxxu`

I add here some info that could be useful to solve the problem:

```
iwconfig
wlx503eaa8e92ca  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s3    no wireless extensions.
```

I'm not a linux user, then I dont know if that is uncommon. But it seems to be everything switched off...

Thank you.

Comment: Release number 19.04 is End-Of-Life and is not supported here. Our support is limited to  assisting you upgrade to a supported version (19.10, 16.04, 18.04, or 20.04, and 19.10 reaches End-Of-Life in a few months).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advise. Let me upgrade my system and then I'll continue this thread.

Comment: I was wrong... My system is 18.04. Is it not supported nither?

Comment: but they don't T.T

Comment: Reopened.since 18.04 is supported (see first comment). I have voted to reopen.  And, 8192eu does = rtl8192eu as 'rtl' is ReaLTek https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8192eu-software

Comment: Ok, one less. Now I ask why the network list is empty... There is a hint, maybe: sometimes it shows me a network (only one) but after a minute or two it disappears. It looks like the antenna power was very weak.

Comment: I added some info to the question. Thank you.